# How to Update Cabal for Haskell IDE (Leksah) on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, ide, haskell

I want to install Leksah so I can learn how to code in Haskell. So I've installed the latest version of ghc (correctly I hope). But **I lack the latest version of Cabal for Leksah**. I cannot seem to install it. I have version 1.24 while the latest is 1.24. I've updated Cabal before going through the following, as well as downloaded version 1.24. I still get the following responses. When I try to install in terminal by typing:

```
cabal install cabal cabal-install
```

I get the following response:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: cabal-0.0.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: youProbablyWantCapitalCabal (dependency of cabal-0.0.0.0)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

When I type the following:

```
cabal install foo
```

I get the following response:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: foo-1.0 (user goal)
trying: base-4.8.2.0/installed-0d6... (dependency of foo-1.0)
trying: containers-0.5.6.2/installed-593... (dependency of foo-1.0)
next goal: haskell98 (dependency of foo-1.0)
rejecting: haskell98-2.0.0.3 (conflict: base==4.8.2.0/installed-0d6...,
haskell98 => base>=4.7 && <4.8)
rejecting: haskell98-2.0.0.2 (conflict: base==4.8.2.0/installed-0d6...,
haskell98 => base==4.6.*)
rejecting: haskell98-2.0.0.1 (conflict: containers =>
array==0.5.1.0/installed-960..., haskell98 => array>=0.3 && <0.5)
rejecting: haskell98-2.0.0.0 (conflict: containers =>
array==0.5.1.0/installed-960..., haskell98 => array>=0.3 && <0.4)
rejecting: haskell98-1.1.0.1, 1.1.0.0, 1.0.1.1 (conflict:
base==4.8.2.0/installed-0d6..., haskell98 => base>=3 && <4.6)
rejecting: haskell98-1.0.1.0 (conflict: base==4.8.2.0/installed-0d6...,
haskell98 => base<4.6)
rejecting: haskell98-1.0 (conflict: base==4.8.2.0/installed-0d6..., 
haskell98
=> base<4.3)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

I even downloaded cabal 1.24. Terminal tells me I currently have version 1.22.6 installed and that I'm using version 1.22.5 of the Cabal library.

How can I update Cabal? Should I try installing Leksah without updating Cabal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a clue in that slightly cryptic error message where it says: `next goal: youProbablyWantCapitalCabal (dependency of cabal-0.0.0.0)`

The [library package is called `Cabal` not `cabal`](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/251).  Try running: `cabal install Cabal cabal-install`